# Gambling in multiple rounds with a maximum permitted bankroll and favorable or unfavourable probabilities

Tags: optimization, expected-value, games, value-iteration

*This is based on a [deleted question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/641101/gamblers-problem-in-a-fixed-number-of-rounds), with the premises clarified to my understanding.*

You are gambling in a casino with particular rules:

- Bets are paid off at even amounts, so if you win a round you get your bet returned plus the same amount as your winnings, while if you lose a round then you lose your bet
- The probability of you winning a round is constant but not necessarily $\frac12$, and each round is independent
- There are a known fixed number of rounds and you must bet in all of them unless your bankroll falls to $0$
- Your bet must be a positive integer up to the limit of your bankroll, so at least $1$ if your bankroll is positive, though the amount each time is at your discretion and can change from round to round and be based on your bankroll at the time
- If, after you win a round, your bankroll exceeds a specified amount then the excess is transferred to a "savings account" which you cannot touch until all the rounds have finished; this is more restrictive than there being a rule about a maximum bet
- Your aim is to maximise the expected final amount you have in your bankroll plus your savings account

Given the amount you start with, the probability of winning a round, the number of rounds, and the maximum permitted bankroll, **what is the optimal strategy and the expected final amount?**  How does this change with the probability of winning a round and the number of rounds?  Should you always bet as much as possible when the probability of winning a round is more than $\frac12$ and as little as possible when the probability of winning a round is less than $\frac12$?

Answer (score 0):

The following R code attempts to do the calculation backwards, so looking at the number of rounds remaining and the optimal choice for each possible level of bankroll at the start of each round (remembering that if your bankroll is ever $0$ you have no choice as you cannot bet).  These optimal choices can change as the number of remaining rounds can change

One key point is that if you ever bet more than the difference between the maximum permitted bankroll and your actual bankroll then you may add to your savings account.  Another key point is that given sufficient future rounds, the probability that your bankroll will eventually diminish to $0$ tends to increase even when the game is in your favour; if this happens then you still have whatever is in your savings account.

It turns out that the type of optimal strategy depends on whether the probability of winning a round is $p=0$ or $p=1$ or $p=\frac12$ or $0<p<\frac12$ or $\frac12 < p <1$. It also depends on whether there are a small number of rounds remaining or a large number. In more detail:

- If $p=0$ then you are going to lose every round.  If there are fewer rounds than your starting bankroll then bet the minimum $1$ each time and walk away with what remains; if there are at least as many rounds as your starting bankroll then you will be left with nothing whatever strategy you choose.
- If $p=1$ then you are going to win every round.  Bet your whole bankroll each time, and if that reaches the maximum and you put amounts in the savings account then keep betting the maximum.
- If $p=\frac12$ then each bet is fair and this is a martingale.  So any strategy has the same final expectation, equal to your starting bankroll, and you can do whatever entertains you most.
- If $0<p<\frac12$ then your expectation is that your bankroll is likely to diminish the more you bet and the more rounds there are. A strategy of betting the minimum $1$ each time can make sense if there are only a few rounds remaining in the hope you can finish with something, but is less than optimal if there are a large number of rounds remaining as a risky bet can reduce the high probability of walking away with nothing and in some cases can increase the probability of managing to put something in the safety of the savings account.
- If $\frac12 <p<1$ then your expectation is that your bankroll and savings account are likely to increase the more you bet and the more rounds there are. A strategy of betting all your bankroll  each time can make sense if there are only a few rounds remaining in the hope this maximises your expectation, but is less than optimal if there are a large number of rounds remaining as an unlikely but possible long sequence of losses can reduce your bankroll to $0$ (even if you have amounts in the savings account) and shut you out of future profitable gambles

.

```
bestbetsandexpectations <- function(pwin, brmax, nrounds){  
  newexpectationfrombankroll <- matrix(0, nrow=2*brmax+1, ncol=nrounds+1)
  newexpectationfrombankroll[1:(brmax+1), 1] <- 0:brmax
  bestbetfrombankroll <- matrix(0, nrow=2*brmax+1, ncol=nrounds+1)
  for (remainrounds in 1:nrounds){
    for (br in 1:brmax){
      possbets <- 1:br
      possexpectations <- (1-pwin) *  
         newexpectationfrombankroll[br-possbets+1, remainrounds] + 
         pwin * ifelse(br+possbets <= brmax,  
         newexpectationfrombankroll[br+possbets+1, remainrounds],
         br+possbets-brmax+ newexpectationfrombankroll[brmax+1, remainrounds])
      newexpectationfrombankroll[br+1, remainrounds+1] <- max(possexpectations)
      bestbetfrombankroll[br+1, remainrounds+1] <- min(
         which(possexpectations == max(possexpectations)))
      }
    }
  return(list(bestbet=bestbetfrombankroll[2:(brmax+1),-1],
              expectations=newexpectationfrombankroll[2:(brmax+1),-1]))
  }
```

With a maximum bankroll of $7$ and up to $9$ rounds, the results (with columns being the number of rounds remaining and rows being the bankroll at the start of each round, the first matrix being the optimal bet and the second the expected final bankroll plus savings account) are for $p=0.7$:

```
> bestbetsandexpectations(pwin=0.7, brmax=7, nrounds=9)
$bestbet
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9]
[1,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1
[2,]    2    2    2    2    2    2    1    1    1
[3,]    3    3    3    3    2    2    2    2    2
[4,]    4    4    4    3    3    3    3    3    2
[5,]    5    5    5    3    3    3    2    2    2
[6,]    6    6    6    4    4    4    3    3    3
[7,]    7    7    7    5    5    5    4    4    4

$expectations
     [,1]  [,2]   [,3]    [,4]     [,5]      [,6]      [,7]      [,8]      [,9]
[1,]  1.4  1.96  2.744  3.7044  4.37668  4.907644  5.442587  5.986077  6.516641
[2,]  2.8  3.92  5.292  6.2524  7.01092  7.775124  8.551539  9.309486 10.038082
[3,]  4.2  5.88  7.252  8.2124  9.14732 10.113208 10.966729 11.774655 12.570151
[4,]  5.6  7.56  8.932 10.0156 11.10732 12.073208 12.926729 13.734655 14.547174
[5,]  7.0  8.96 10.332 11.4800 12.57172 13.563480 14.488398 15.391898 16.266725
[6,]  8.4 10.36 11.732 12.8800 13.97172 14.963480 15.888398 16.791898 17.666725
[7,]  9.8 11.76 13.132 14.2800 15.37172 16.363480 17.288398 18.191898 19.066725
```

These patterns continue with even more rounds: in the $p=0.7$ case and a maximum bankroll of $7$, you should never bet more than $1$ if there are $459$ or more remaining rounds no matter what your bankroll, and only move to a more aggressive betting strategy when the the number of remaining rounds is smaller.

With the same maximum bankroll of $7$ and up to $9$ rounds, but with $p=0.3$:

```
> bestbetsandexpectations(pwin=0.3, brmax=7, nrounds=9)
$bestbet
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9]
[1,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1
[2,]    1    1    1    2    2    2    2    2    2
[3,]    1    1    1    1    3    3    3    3    3
[4,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    4    4    4
[5,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    5    5
[6,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1
[7,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1

$expectations
     [,1] [,2]  [,3]   [,4]    [,5]     [,6]      [,7]      [,8]     [,9]
[1,]  0.6 0.48 0.360 0.2988 0.25200 0.216000 0.1886436 0.1641600 0.151200
[2,]  1.6 1.20 0.996 0.8400 0.72000 0.628812 0.5472000 0.5040000 0.468000
[3,]  2.6 2.20 1.800 1.5372 1.32000 1.200000 1.0800000 0.9741179 0.872928
[4,]  3.6 3.20 2.800 2.4000 2.09604 1.824000 1.6800000 1.5600000 1.449883
[5,]  4.6 4.20 3.800 3.4000 3.00000 2.667228 2.3568000 2.1600000 2.049883
[6,]  5.6 5.20 4.800 4.4000 4.00000 3.600000 3.2470596 2.9097600 2.661883
[7,]  6.6 6.20 5.800 5.4000 5.00000 4.600000 4.2000000 3.8329417 3.486715
```

These patterns continue with even more rounds: in the $p=0.3$ case and a maximum bankroll of $7$, you should bet your full bankroll if there are $11$ or more remaining rounds, and only move to a more restricted betting strategy when the the number of remaining rounds is smaller.